# Need help placing tooltip to the right of label

Tags: html, css, html-table, tooltip

I have a table of property information and have a tooltip for each header. I need to place the tooltip to the right of the label, with it vertically centered. I'm in the scheme of things a beginner with CSS and manipulating html elements with it. Here's a JSFiddle with my code. It's a big project, so I wasn't able to get all the css such that it'll match the included picture, but hopefully enough that you'll have the general idea.

Here's a sample of my table header if you just need a glance.

```
<th rowspan="2" data-field="Address">
  <span>Property<br />address</span>
    <a style="position: relative; top: 25%; right: 0;" tabindex="0" role="button" 
      data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-trigger="hover click" 
      title="Property address" data-content="An all-inclusive list of properties associated 
      to your agreement">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign info-popover"></span>
    </a>
</th>
```

[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/gsxb0c65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could accomplish this is by using `position`.

You would start with making the `<th style="position: relative;">`, which will allow items positioned inside of it to respect its own bounds.

Next, you would take your `<a>` inside and make it `position: absolute;`, like below:

```
th > a {
    position: absolute;
    //these two rules put it vertically centered no matter what inside of the container
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    //and then set the right to however far you'd like it away from the right side of the <th>
    right: 20px;
}
```

You'll probably want to `text-align: center;` the `<a>` as well, so the icon is always in the center of it the way you have it displayed. But this rule should allow you to get a lot closer to what you're looking for.

**EDIT:** Added updates to a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/2468jgew/

**EDIT2:** Here's another StackOverflow post explaining the rules I laid out for you [Transform: translate(-50%, -50%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184458/transform-translate-50-50)