# Understanding how centering a div works with bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I came across some code that nicely centers a login box, which I used. But then I realised I actually wanted my login box to be 25% from the left instead of 50%. However I have no clue how the code actually works. When I google centering elements it suggests putting left: x% and margin of -x/2% along with absolute. This code doesn't do any of that but works.

I am unsure how it's working though, I wonder if someone could explain so that I can fiddle with it to reposition.

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center>
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle located here](https://jsfiddle.net/rcmd7w95/)

It seems that without the bootstrap css it doesn't quite center it properly.

My goal is simply to be able to 'center' it anywhere so as the page is resized it always remains at the same percentage position I specify.

Could someone explain how this is working so I can understand it myself? Or if this is actually a weird way to do it perhaps give clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Hey NP - just following up. Did we answer your question? If there is more any of us can help with, please add a comment or edit your question to let us know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose an answer, or add your own and let us know what worked for you. *Thanks!*

Comment: Yep that video and explanation put me well on my way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major, core, difference between Bootstap3 and Bootstrap4 is changing the fundamental Grid System from using Floats for alignment to using Flexbox.

Therefore, understanding flexbox is important, and useful even apart from Bootstrap. And, fortunately, it's also pretty easy.

Flexbox requires two things:

1. A parent container *(e.g. DIV, section, aside, p, etc)*
2. One or more child elements *(e.g. div, p, img, etc)*

You turn flexbox ***on*** on the parent: `display:flex;`

Then, there are various *switches* (just a handful of them). Some are set on the parent (as in the case of `justify-content`) but others might be set on the items (as with `flex-grow:1`)

Since you want to *understand* how to manage this properly, I suggest you take the 20 minutes necessary to view the following, excellent, fast-paced flexbox tutorial:

[YouTube tutorial - fast-paced and best-of-breed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Here is a great cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) for Flexbox.

***Watch the tutorial and in 30 mins from now your problem will be solved -- and you'll know flexbox.***

<sub>P.S. I have no connection to the video or its presenter - I was fortunate to discover it, and now pass it along.</sub>

Comment: Thanks I will watch the tutorial when I get home from work!

Comment: Oh man that video was amazing, I wish I had seen that 2 years ago!

Comment: Exactly how I felt about it. Somewhere there's an ivy league college missing its best instructor. *And, hopefully, knowing flexbox and what it can do will help you to solve this and future alignment problems.*

Answer (score 1):

Div centering with what you mentioned is a **little tricky**, let me explain. 
First of all, your div is **absolute** and stretched from all the sides. Which results in this.

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice, **this covers the whole page**. Because the position is 0 from all the 4 sides

Now just add the `max-width` and `max-height` constraint. This means it is the same as the above snippet, but you just **changed the widths**

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, what happened? The width is a constraint. Next, you did was to specify a height. Notice, the top, bottom, and other locations cause this short div to come in center and boom, it is in the center

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div is basically stretched.

#### What's the best way to center using absolute positioning?

Using this

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, what's better in this? You can edit the top, left, right values to your preferences to achieve responsive views. What I did is just set the value of top to a percentage one. It will remain fix for many views on scaling them. You can **calibrate the views** and achieve the best for you.

### What is the vertical height unit?

This unit `vh` is added to displays to scale according to the height and not the width of the screen. Try this example and notice how the text changes when you edit the height of the browser. Using `vw` for widths.

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Bonus centering method: Flexbox

Flexbox is the **best method** when it comes to centering items in CSS. Just make sure your **parent div and the child div is at the desired height** and use `align-items: center`

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive">hello</div>
```

To center horizontally, just add `justify-content: center`

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive">hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. I typed out a big reply and in doing so understand what I was confused about. I didn't expect setting a width to center it, I figured it would dump it on the left. I guess it's being clever and saying if you want it 0 0 0 0 in all the corners the closest it can do with a max-width is center it. I am not sure why you've used top 40% though. Wasn't it centered with 0?

Comment: I've used `top:40%` for another item. So you can adjust it according to your preferences.  As you mentioned in your question you need something like that. Also added a bonus centering method. :) @NibblyPig

Comment: Wouldn't `top:40%` mean that it's positioned 70% of the way down the screen, if what I said was right? Because 40% of the way down the screen means you have 60% left, so divide by 2... and setting min/max height doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: @NibblyPig Note the CSS settings in that example. I removed everything and just added your positioning and a `top:40%` means it will be positioned 40% always from the top. When the screen resizes, it will still be 40% from the top because the total is decreased. Try the docs if I cannot be clear https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Comment: I see, so it doesn't take into account the height of the item?

Comment: No, it doesn't, if the item's height is changed then you have to adjust it accordingly. For that case, use flexbox. @NibblyPig

Answer (score 0):

The div is centered properly, but the contents inside it are not centered to it. So, you need to use `display: flex` to assign the contents of the absolute div.

I've updated the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/aedo3pv5

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap is very easy:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="box" class="offset-3"> box content </div>
</div>
```

bootstrap grid system is made of rows and cols and it is a mobile first framework.

- offset: is left space of an element, in this case 3 refers to the number of columns, since grid system is made of 12 columns, 3 is equals to 25%.

you may also want to take a look at [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Comment: But it wouldn't be exactly 25% depending on the width of the content, which is why `absolute` is used and some other kind of trickery I think

Comment: offset do not depend on the width of the element, it gives 3 columns space to the left so if box is a child of the body it will have 25% of space from the left. Bootstrap has a very solid and tested grid system

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform :translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center; color:white">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

explanation here [Transform: translate(-50%, -50%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184458/transform-translate-50-50)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4, you need to add two simple class in a row. and you need to use position

```css
.Absolute-Center {
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

```css
.Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 100vh;">
        <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive" style="text-align: center">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```