# How to vertically center the starting point for a group of animated divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a css animation where I need the initial position of all animated elements (everything in the 'index' class) to be perfectly centered vertically. I've tried using the flex method shown in other answers, but it isn't seeming to work. Any ideas? Here is a JS Fiddle with all the code of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/149gwure/2/

```
#container {
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align each animated `div` element to the center of their container using this.

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Since the their container/parent is the entire window, they will all align to the center of the screen both vertically `top: 50%;` and horizontally `left: 50%;`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46184660/5999686)  explains why it works pretty well

I implemented this in your JSFiddle demo:

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ajerpzL/)

Comment: Perfect! This did work exactly as I needed it to. Thank you.